# Find N bits of most significant bit of a BigInteger(msb)

Tags: java, math, biginteger

i want to find n bits most significant bit of a  BigInteger and return it as a byte type.
it's my home work and i know very little thinks about it.
please help me to resolve it.its very necessary  for me.
this is the method that must be implemented:

```
 /**
     * *
     * Gets N numbers of bits from the MOST SIGNIFICANT BIT (inclusive).
     *
     * @param value Source from bits will be extracted
     * @param n The number of bits taken
     * @return The n most significant bits from value
     */
    private byte msb(BigInteger value, int n) {

        return 0x000;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean, if the value is `0b000001011100110111101101` = `0x05CDED` = `380397` and n is `6`, you want `0b101110` = `0x2E` = `46`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `bitLength()` in `java.math.BigInteger` which returns the number of bits in the number.  You can use this method to retrieve the `n` most significant bits as:

```
    int n = 3;
    BigInteger r = BigInteger.valueOf(23);
    BigInteger f = r.shiftRight(r.bitLength() - n);
    Byte result = Byte.valueOf(f.toString());
    System.out.println(result);
```

This prints `5` as expected.

Comment: @Mehran You are welcome,  upvote the answer if it solved your problem :).

Comment: i can't up vote.because i'm beginner in stackoverflow